# The following classes could not be instantiated,android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**What happen is it? need help~** 
i try many way but still cannot solve it

**Rendering Problems** The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.

**Exception Details** java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper. (Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:133)   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:110)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy stack to clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added the dependency for `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'` in your app `gradle.build` file

Comment: I already added the dependency (compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0')

Comment: Try to add the newest version of the library, or try what Android Studio is suggesting - to clear cache and refresh layout

Comment: already tried, but the activity layout was imported by other application, its work well, I copied to my package then the problem occurred. Means I opened two android studios, the first android studio is imported, the second one is my project, I just copied from the first, and got this problem, the first don't have such problem, I already tried to add latest library and dependency to my project.